# How to reload fragment when tab is selected?

Tags: android

I have created a simple app with 3 tab TAB1, TAB2, TAB3
When i select the TAB1 adjacent TAB2 get loaded into memory after that when i press on the TAB2 or TAB3 my content on the TAB2 will not get refresh.

If i click tab in the sequence TAB1->TAB2->TAB1->TAB2 my fragment will not refresh

I want load the selected tab each time when i select the tab.

I am using the following code to load the fragment on tab selected

```
public class SampleFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"HOME", "BEACON", "NEARBY"};
private int[] imageResId = {
        R.drawable.home,
        R.drawable.beacon,
        R.drawable.nearby
};
private Context context;

public SampleFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (position == 0)
        fragment = new FragmentTab1();
    if (position == 1)
        fragment = new FragmentTab2();
    if (position == 2)
        fragment = new FragmentTab3();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, 32, 32);
    // Replace blank spaces with image icon
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("   " + tabTitles[position]);
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
}
```

Comment: it is a TabHost or a custom view?

Comment: can you post some code of your fragments? just the code of one of them is more than sufficient :)

Comment: Nothing done on the fragment code

Comment: have you tryed using the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP? Or better, you can call Finish() method and re-create fragment every times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FragmentPagerAdapter: 
FragmentPagerAdapter stores the whole fragment in memory, and could increase a memory overhead if a large amount of fragments are used in ViewPager.

FragmentStatePagerAdapter:
FragmentStatePagerAdapter only stores the savedInstanceState of fragments, and destroys all the fragments when they lose focus. Therefore FragmentStatePagerAdapter should be used when we have to use dynamic fragments, like fragments with widgets, as their data could be stored in the savedInstanceState

USE CASES:
FragmentPagerAdapter should be used when we need to store the whole fragment in memory. When I say the whole fragment is kept in memory it means, its instances wont be destroyed and would create a memory overhead. Therefore it is advised to use FragmentPagerAdapter only when there are low number of fragments for ViewPager. It would be even better if the fragments are static, since they would not be having large amount of objects whose instances would be stored.

In your case if your using Listview, recyclerview or any heavy work you should use 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter' other wise 'FragmentPagerAdapter'

Answer (score 2):

```
Your_Pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == WHATEVER) {
                //do your Staff

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

You can visit here for more information

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html